# Loadrunner VUGen - Tru-Client - How do you upload a file?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I've recorded a script using the TruClient protocol in which part of the business process for the web-app under test requires uploading a .pdf file. To initiate the upload, you click on the "Upload file" button found on the page, which produces the Windows' filepicker. The file is selected and then uploaded to the application.

Upon playing this script back in VUGen, the script timesout at the upload file transaction. Does anyone know a workaround to this? I'm using Loadrunner VUGen 12.55.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The standard file system dialogs are part of the windows common dialog set (file/open/save/print preview/...) and are not a part of the browser code.  If you need to operate an operating system common dialog then consider a GUI virtual user which will be able to (1) identify, (2) Operate and (3) Validate OS objects.

Or, consider an HTTP virtual user where you can simply change the filename for upload on the HTTP stream

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to do the former. Any pointers? As for the latter, I assume you mean WebHTTP protocol in VUGen? Recording the script in WebHTTP has proved to be a disaster. It works better in TruClient given the time I have.

Comment: GUI Virtual User - QTP driven.  See documentation.   Define, "disaster..."

Comment: In this case, I can't seem to get the script to complete the Bizflow form (it's an eBiz application) and move the record through the business process using the WebHTTP protocol. I've made what I think are the necessary correlations, but I am not getting the correct responses and/or successfully creating the initial record.

Answer (score 0):

This is my example.

You can create a parameter "P_Upload_File" for upload_file, and it's value is an absolute path.
[image]

And you can use Set on filefox. And specific Path with this parameter, in this example is P_Upload_File.
[image]